# In PyParsing, remove all quotes from the parsed result

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'd like to parse a string which is a comma-separated list of double-quoted strings. At first (after `from pyparsing import *`) I tried this:

```
In [36]: expression = delimitedList(dblQuotedString, delim=",")

In [37]: expression.parseString('"foo","bar"')
Out[37]: (['"foo"', '"bar"'], {})
```

This generates the expected matches, but doesn't remove the quotes. So I tried adding an `addParseAction(removeQuotes)`:

```
In [34]: expression = delimitedList(dblQuotedString, delim=",").addParseAction(r
    ...: emoveQuotes)

In [35]: expression.parseString('"foo","bar"')
Out[35]: (['foo'], {})
```

This removes the quotes on `'foo'`, but now the `'bar'` result is missing. How can I make the expression such that the result is `(['foo', 'bar'], {})`?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can use the `QuotedString` object with its `quoteChar` set to `"`. This object automatically removes the quotes:

```
In [40]: expression = delimitedList(QuotedString(quoteChar='"'), delim=',')

In [41]: expression.parseString('"foo","bar"')
Out[41]: (['foo', 'bar'], {})
```

Comment: The right way to use the `removeQuotes` parse action is to attach it to the `dblQuotedString` expression, not the `delimitedList`: `expression = delimitedList(dblQuotedString.addParseAction(removeQuotes), delim=",")` But using `QuotedString` works just as well.